# cross-env not setting NODE_ENV

Tags: npm, webpack

I want to set environment variables to configure URL at runtime.
I use webpack to bundle the js and here is the plugin defined to make the `NODE_ENV` available during compile time.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env':{
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    //'TARGET_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.TARGET_ENV)
  }
})
```

Here are the `yarn` I want to execute according to the targeted environment:

```
"test-kubernetes": "cross-env NODE_ENV=kubernetes-cluster webpack && yarn run testenv",
"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode=production",
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --mode=development && webpack-dev-server --hot",
```

However `process.env.NODE_ENV` is `undefined` at runtime.
This issue seems to be related to [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env?activeTab=readme) since using:

`SET NODE_ENV=kubernetes-cluster`

instead of

`cross-env NODE_ENV=kubernetes-cluster`

on my Windows machine makes things work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a regression since 5.2.0 for Windows environment. I managed to make things work switching back to 5.1.6.
Reference issue: https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env/issues/185